# Finding the roots of $x^3+ax+a=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

If the roots $x_1,x_2,x_3$ of the equation $x^3+ax+a=0$ satisfy $$\frac{x_1^2}{x_2}+\frac{x_2^2}{x_3}+\frac{x_3^2}{x_1}=-8$$ then the roots of the equation are?

I wrote the [Vieta formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) down but then I'm stuck.Please give your suggestions.

Comment: Multiply through by $x_1x_2x_3$ and use the equation $x_i^3 = -a(x_i+1)$ to get ridd of the $x^3$ terms. Then in the end you can try to use Vieta's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{x_1^2}{x_2}+\frac{x_2^2}{x_3}+\frac{x_3^2}{x_1}=-8 \iff \frac{x_1^3}{x_1x_2}+\frac{x_2^3}{x_2x_3}+\frac{x_3^3}{x_1x_2}=-8 \iff \frac{-ax_1-a}{x_1x_2}+\frac{-ax_2-a}{x_2x_3}+\frac{-ax_3-a}{x_1x_3}=-8 \iff \frac{a}{x_1x_2}+\frac{a}{x_2x_3} + \frac{a}{x_1x_3} + \frac{a}{x_1}+ \frac{a}{x_2}+ \frac{a}{x_3}=8 (1)$

Because $x_1x_2x_3=-a$ (Vieta), from (1) we have:

$-(x_1 + x_2 +x_3) - (x_1x_2 + x_1x_3+x_2x_3) = 8$

Should be easy from here.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)=0\\\Rightarrow x^3-(x_1+x_2+x_3)x^2+(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)x-x_1x_2x_3=0$$
So:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=0\,\, ,\,\,x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=a\,\, ,\,\, x_1x_2x_3=-a$$
multiply your equation about roots by $x_1x_2x_3=-a$ and use original equation (a guy commented) and first of up equations, you get:
$$x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=-8$$
So:
$$a=-8$$